# Зашить информацию в ссылку на приложение Google Play

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

На некоторых сайтах (например Приват24 для Украины) есть в футере иконка андроида при нажатии на которую вы можете перейти в Google Play и скачать приложение для сервиса на котором вы находились с компа, но вот возник вопрос, можно ли как-то зашить в эту ссылку например логин, если нужно будет входить в приложении, то есть например вы скачали по ссылке это приложение и вам нужно ввести только пароль, так как логин уже был прошит. Может я не сильно понятно задал вопрос если что спрашивайте, буду благодарен за любую помощь и советы. Если предложенный мной способ костыльный или вообще тупой, то может можно как-то минимизировать ввод логинов и паролей в приложении.
P.S. Я видел на сайте Google Play в документации пример ссылки на приложение и там в конце есть только название пакета, но может можно как-то подтянуть логин к примеру.

Comment: Думаю, можно протащить это через [отслеживание кампаний](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns#google-play-campaigns).

Comment: Распространённый способ быстрого входа с мобильного устройства – через авторизацию у провайдера, например у Google, т. к. почти на всех Андроидах уже выполнен вход в такой аккаунт.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

однозначно нет.
чтобы сделать это пришлосьбы перекомпилировать Apk или загружать префы в рут директорию.но это слишком сложно.
как облегчить вход в аккаунт?
используйте QRCode например на сайте вы качаете приложение, и потом сканируете QRCode с монитора компьютера. небольшой пример: на сайте данные логин+пароль парсются в JSON и преобразуются в QRCode потом в приложении через какую-то библиотеку для QRCode и получаете данные формата JSON и вытягиваете из него логин+пароль.

Comment: (лучше будет использовать апи токены для повышения безопасности)